# Calculating the value function by integral in reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

In reinforcement learning, the value function of a state is defined as its expected return, or $ v_{\pi} (s) = \mathbb{E} \left[ G_t | S_t = s \right]$, where $\pi$ is a policy and $G_t$ the return.

I know that we can express the value of a state $v_\pi(s)$ in terms of the value of other states $v_\pi(s')$ , via the Bellman equation. However, I got stuck when I tried to formulate this expectation in integral form.

Just like $\mathbb {E}(X) = \int x f(x) dx$, I calculated $\mathbb{E} \left[ G_t | S_t = s \right]$ and got $\int g_t f(g_t)dg_t$. I was confused by two things:

- The distribution $f(g_t)$ refers to the probability distribution of the values the return $G_t$ can take at time $t$. How would you find this?
- How does this distribution link to the probability distribution of the policy $\pi(a|s)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "find" the distribution by playing the environments a bunch of times and collecting samples. There is no straightforward way to find the distribution of the return, and the relationship between the return and the policy $\pi$ can be arbitrarily complex -- imagine an environment which gives reward of 1 if $M(a,s)$ halts (where $M$ is some turing machine), and 0 otherwise. Even the immediate reward of this environment is undecidable, nevermind the expected cumulative return.

At best you can write down some very general equation like $F(G) = \int_{\mathcal{T}_G} p(\tau) d\tau$ where $\mathcal{T}_G$ is the set of trajectories with return of at most $G$ and $p(\tau)$ is the probability/density of taking trajectory $\tau$, which can of course be further expanded into some expression containing $\pi(a|s)$. ($F$ is the cdf of $f(G)$).